# How many hours are in a day?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I just ran across this little gem:

[image]

How many hours make up a day in Pillars of Eternity?

Comment: Just a sidenote: in real life, it is perfectly possible for a day to have 25 hours, namely when the daylight savings switch happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this wiki page about an in game book, The Iroccian Calender, a day in Pillars of Eternity lasts 26 hours.

Source: http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Anni_Iroccio

Comment: The in game book does not actually state the hours, that information is just included in the article as a convenience to the reader. It was also changed from 27 to 26 after discussion on the talk page about an ingame-experiment.